# non root access to ioctl for WIFI scan

Tags: linux, kernel, wifi, root, ioctl

I'm working on implementing iwlist python version. Here is a description of how iwlist works on Linux OS [How does iwlist() command scans the wireless networks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925669/how-does-iwlist-command-scans-the-wireless-networks) what it does is to scan all nearby wifi access points, show a list of their ESSID, MAC address, signal/noise level, etc.

iwlist uses ioctl SIOCSIWSCAN to trigger a scan. Then it uses SIOCGIWSCAN to get scan results. For security reason I have to implement this without root access. But both these two command have to be run as root. The python equivalent iwlist has been implemented already http://pythonwifi.wikispot.org/ However it uses the same ioctl.

I'm wondering if it is possible to work around this without sudo. Or, besides ioctl, if there's other ways to implement a non-sudo iwlist.

Comment: Try it.  Then ask if you run into issues.  We won't do your research for you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you also don't want to use setuid for security reasons. You might want to try the [capability](http://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities) system instead and [set](http://linux.die.net/man/8/setcap) the required capability on your binary. I don't know exactly which capability you need, probably one of the *CAP_NET_** or *CAP_SYS_** capabilities.